# Handling escape characters in JSON response in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, json

I have a rather simple issue that for some reason I can find a help for using SO and Google.
I am receiving a JSON reply that looks like this:

```
"{
\"data\": [
    {
        \"type\": \"gif\",
        \"id\": \"FiGiRei2ICzzG\",
        \"url\": \"http: //giphy.com/gifs/funny-cat-FiGiRei2ICzzG\",
        \"bitly_gif_url\": \"http: //gph.is/1fIdLOl\",
        \"bitly_url\": \"http: //gph.is/1fIdLOl\",
        \"embed_url\": \"http: //giphy.com/embed/FiGiRei2ICzzG\",
        \"username\": \"\",
        \"source\": \"http: //tumblr.com\", etc........
```

So it's a standard JSON but with \ escape characters sprinkled in.
Now those escape characters I am trying to remove to parse data from the JSON.
Tried the .replace of the string and some other solutions, but for some reason I stay with the escape characters..
Thanks!!
This is the code I used to do the request

```
 public static void GetRequest()
    {
        string sFullURL = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=";
        string sSearchTerm = "funny+cat";
        string sContent;
        string sAPIKey = "&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC";
        string sLimit = "&limit=1";
        string sFullRequest = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=funny+cat&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC";
        HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(sFullURL + sSearchTerm + sAPIKey + sLimit));
        WebReq.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusCode);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(WebResp.Server);
        Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
        sContent = _Answer.ReadToEnd();
        sContent = Regex.Replace(sContent, @"\\", ""); 
    }
```

Comment: Show the code you tried

Comment: are you checking the value in debugger? if yes, then the backslashes are not there. I don't see any escaped quotes when i open that url in the browser. Debugger shows an escaped version of the string. You can click on the small magnification icon on the left of the debugger value preview to view the actual value

Comment: I see these values in the debugger. Maybe it doesn't show the correct string?

Comment: Oh I see that now, when I ran it through the             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sContent) I could see that it is in the correct format..

Comment: @PavelZagalsky glad you got it to work... i've added an answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're getting confused by the value in the debugger. The debugger windows shows an escaped version of the string.

[image]

You can click on the little magnification icon to open the string in a "text visualizer" to see the actual value of the string.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You're trying to escape the \ character twice using regular escaping ("\\") and verbatim strings (@"string").
Try

```
sContent = Regex.Replace(sContent, @"\", "");
```